# Dot Product in Python without NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, operation

Is there a way that you can preform a dot product of two lists that contain values without using NumPy or the Operation module in Python? So that the code is as simple as it could get?

For example:

```
V_1=[1,2,3]
V_2=[4,5,6]

Dot(V_1,V_2)
```

Answer: 32

Comment: I just meant using lists that contained values within them.

Comment: I will update the question

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Without numpy, you can write yourself a function for the dot product which uses `zip` and `sum`.

```
>>> def dot(v1, v2):
...     return sum(x*y for x, y in zip(v1, v2))
... 
>>> dot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
32
```

As of Python 3.10, you can use `zip(v1, v2, strict=True)` to ensure that `v1` and `v2` have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

```
def dot_product(x, y):
    dp = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        dp += (x[i]*y[i])
    return dp

sample1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
sample2 = [2,1,1,1,1]

dot_product(sample1, sample2) #16
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use @ operator from python.
For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([25, 2, 5])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2])

print(x@y)
12
```

Comment: The `@` operator is implemented *by* NumPy; it's not part of native Python.